# Alternate for gembox.sreadsheet dependency for java 17

Tags: java-17, java-module, gembox-spreadsheet

We are using gembox spreadsheet for calculation via workbook. There are conflicts in com.w3c.dom package as it available in Java 17 default. Any ways to prevent the same

Gembox spreadsheet jar is in classpath and it's is conflicting with java 17 com.w3c.dom package

Comment: Are you sure, you want to stick around with [gempbox](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/news/gembox-spreadsheet-for-java-retirement) with Java? If yes, your only good way would be to refactor the source code, build and update the dependency in your own project in case of split packages.